# How can I get an hour ago on dart with flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

here was wrong.

```
final anHourAgo = (new DateTime.now()) - Duration(minutes: Duration.minutesPerHour);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is resolved.

```
final anHourAgo = (new DateTime.now()).subtract(new Duration(minutes: Duration.minutesPerHour));
```

Answer (score 2):

This should Work :

```
Text(TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: 1))).format(context)),
```

Comment: Thank you. I also found one of the answers.